# NameError: name 'wantedKey1' is not defined

Tags: python, json, scripting

my code :

```
for key,di in json.loads(json_data).items():
  if wantedkey1 in di['entry'][0]:
        print found
        found=True
        print found  
        print(wantedKey1+ " : " +di['entry'][0][wantedKey1])
        break
```

my error :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "downloads.py", line 61, in <module>
    print(wantedKey1+ " : " +di['entry'][0][wantedKey1])
NameError: name 'wantedKey1' is not defined
```

PleaSE help why it it giving this error . NameError: name 'wantedKey1' is not defined

Comment: Python is case-sensitive. `wantedkey1` != `wantedKey1`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your cases, you initially set it as wantedkey1 with no caps, but then use it with a capital K later: those are two different names.